Erro em deploy no Cloud functions quando uso o axios
Olá!
Estou precisando criar um endpoint na minha api do google Cloud Functions, essa endpoit deve fazer uma requisição a um servidor externo.
Localmente tudo funciona, porém quando tento fazer o deploy da erro.
Esse erro só aparece quando importo e tento usar o axios.
Erro:

Could not create or update Cloud Run service sgedu-api, Container
Healthcheck failed. Revision 'sgedu-api-00032-kin' is not ready and
cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and
listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment
variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the
container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The
health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might
contain more information

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto";
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(url);
    res.status(200).send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro ao conectar :", error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Erro ao conectar ao SGEDU");
  }

  res.status(200).send("Conexão com bem-sucedida.");
});

Este é um exemplo do método que criei só para tentar descobrir o que estava acontecendo.

Boas-vindas. A pergunta não faz parte do escopo do Stack Overflow em Português. Mesmo assim, para adiantar e ajudar, o erro está descrito na mensagem, você deve sempre ler. A mensagem de erro diz que o problema é na porta que tentou definir, referindo-se a porta 8080, que provavelmente é a porta que você configurou no .env da sua aplicação, e isso não é esperado pelo container, corrija a porta ou solicite o suporte técnico da sua hospedagem.
